# Directories containing brackets [ ] in the name being deleted in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell for the first time here, so please go easy on me...

I've written a script that checks a directory and, for any directory inside that is empty, it is to be deleted. The problem I'm having is with directories containing brakets -> [] in the directory name. Even if the directory isn't empty, it's still being deleted. Can anyone help? Here's the code I'm using:

```
$path = "C:\path\to\directory"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

I don't fully understand the code above, I found it online. But it's working for directories that don't have the brackets.

For a directory with the name of "**SummerPhotos**" that contains a file, the directory is not deleted. -> Good

For a directory that is empty, it is deleted. -> Good

For a directory named "**SummerPhotos[2009]**", it's being deleted even if it contains a file. -> Bad

I googled and read that powershell treats brackets as wildcards, but I'm not sure how to get around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to remove non-empty directories, why are you using `-Recurse` in the first place?

Comment: In PowerShell Get-ChildItem the `[]` denote a range, to avoid this don't use `-Path` but `-LiteralPath` inside the Where-Ob ject

Comment: @grawity How to get the last of some stacked directories if not recursing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In PowerShell Get-ChildItem the `[]` denote a range, to avoid this don't use `-Path` but `-LiteralPath` inside the `Where-Object`
- To avoid possible irritations with `$env:path` choose a different
  variable name.

---

```
$Mypath = "C:\path\to\directory"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Mypath -Recurse -Force | 
  Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | 
                                        Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | 
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Confirm
```

In more recent PowerShell versions you can use `Get-ChildItem` parameters `-Directoy` and `-File` instead of `Where {$_.PSIsContainer}`

```
$Mypath = "C:\path\to\directory"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Mypath -Recurse -Force -Directory -EA 0 | 
  Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -File -EA 0 ) -eq $null } | 
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Confirm
```

---

- `-EA 0` is an abbreviation for `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`
- while testing I suggest using `-WhatIf` or `-Confirm` in the Remove-Item cmdlet

Comment: Hey that worked beautifully. Thanks so much!!!